# Find a partition in a postgresql database across its boundaries

Tags: postgresql

How can I find a partition in the database catalog through the range (bounds) information of that partition?
I partitioned a table using a date field and I need to find a partition through that information.
I've seen that I have a "relpartbound" field in the catalog "child" table, but it does not seem to be in an easy way to search.

Comment: `pg_get_expr(relpartbound, ...)` might help

Comment: Ty, @a_horse_with_no_name, your help was pretty usefull

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    nmsp_parent.nspname AS parent_schema,
    parent.relname      AS parent,
    nmsp_child.nspname  AS child_schema,
    child.relname       AS child,
    pg_get_expr(child.relpartbound, child.relfilenode) AS child_bounds
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child ON pg_inherits.inhrelid = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent ON nmsp_parent.oid = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child ON nmsp_child.oid = child.relnamespace
WHERE parent.relname = 'parent_table_name';
```

PostgreSql function "pg_get_expr" will decompile internal form of "child.relpartbound" expression and will give me something more readble like:

```
FOR VALUES FROM ('2017-01-01') TO ('2017-01-02')
```

Ty @a_horse_with_no_name for the great suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
pg_get_expr(child.relpartbound, child.oid)
```

instead of

```
pg_get_expr(child.relpartbound, child.relfilenode)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).