# How to retrieve partitioning boundaries

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have postgres 10+. Assuming I create a declarative partitioned table by RANGE with several partitions.

How can I retrieve the boundaries of a specific partition?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853846/find-a-partition-in-a-postgresql-database-across-its-boundaries ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bounds are stored in the `relpartbound` column of the `pg_class` entry of the partitions. This query prints the names of all partitions and their partition bounds:

```
SELECT t.oid::regclass AS partition,
       pg_get_expr(t.relpartbound, t.oid) AS bounds
FROM pg_inherits AS i
   JOIN pg_class AS t ON t.oid = i.inhrelid
WHERE i.inhparent = 'partitioned_table'::regclass;
```